# No Read/Write SD Card Permissions on Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, sd-card

I'm sorry, I try as often as possible to avoid repeating questions but I've tried the suggestions on previous threads here and elsewhere and I cannot fix it.

I have an SD card I'm trying to open files from on a laptop running Windows 7. Files are fine on XP but I'm getting the message that I do not have permission to open in 7. I've gone in and reset the permissions to 'full control' for everybody for the entire 'E' drive, the specific folder, even tried the individual file.

I've also downloaded and tried to 'Take Ownership' of each via the downloaded registry but nothing is working. I'd appreciate any additional thoughts. Thank you!